# How do I remove the small blank/uncovered space at the bottom of my blogger blog?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a blogger blog, and I need to know how to have the footer entirely cover the bottom of the page. When you scroll to the bottom, there is a small gap between the content container which is obviously black, and the bottom of the browser window. How do I fix this? How do I make the content container stretch to the bottom of the page entirely?

http://blog.substructures.us/

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
.content{
   heigth : 100%;
   padding : 5px;
   margin : 5px;
}
```

Comment: That helped a bit, Dr. Geek. But now I have a horizontal scroll bar, and I'm trying to make the website look entirely fit together, despite it having a blogger blog attached to it. Sorry, I meant horizontal initially*

Answer (score 0):

Changing CSS for **.content-inner** to this will work although there might be a better solution available, so keep looking at answers in this thread.

```
.content-inner {
    margin-top: -20px !important;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I experimented with the answer Dr. Geek gave me, and had a problem with a horizontal scrollbar appearing at the bottom and throwing the pages setup off from the main setup, so I added this to the custom CSS for now:

```
.content{
margin-bottom: -1px;
}
```

It's a very simple fix, and anyone who uses blogger and wants to remove a gap from the bottom of their blog will have this answer hopefully.